# how to make sql script file from entity framework dbcontext

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework, ssms

is is possible to generate sql script from dbcontext of entity framework to create the whole database or at least tables with previously created database via **ssms**.

So when my dbcontext and models are done, can i make sql script witch will be able to recreate the whole db (it can be empty, it doesn't matter).

Now, i know that migrations do that but the problem is that i have many migrations so the code for sql is scattered all over the place.

So, is it possible to make that sql script when I am finished modeling db from code first approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would let EF create DB and than using SSMS you can generate scripts even with data. *Right click db in SSMS > Tasks > Generate Scripts* and then in dialog window where they want you to select file for saving SQL script choose **Advanced**. There you can select what you want to generate.

[image]

Comment: hell yeah, this is perfect :D i kinda know that probably mmsm can do this but didnt know how. thanks men

Answer (score 1):

To do this run the Update-Database command in the Package Manager Console but this time specify the –Script flag so that changes are written to a script rather than applied. [[source]](http://bartwullems.blogspot.mx/2013/05/generate-sql-script-from-entity.html)

```
update-database -script
```

Comment: this wont work on finished db.  ive all ready updated database so i can bring it to final version. after running that command the script is empty

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: after changing my model ive made migration and updated database to final verson. now when i run your command in package management console the sql script is created but its empty. i believe the reason is that ive all ready updated database with the latest migration, and i am pretty sure this command will work only for single migration and now for whole database.

Comment: If you already have a complete database, you should be able to just create a new connection string in your app/web.config pointing to a db that doesn't exist and include the flag -connectionstringname "nameOfConnectionStringInConfig"